# How to apply a formula to a Pandas DataFrame using a rolling window as well as a mean value across this window?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I am trying to implement a small algorithm that creates a new column in my DataFrame depending on wether a certain condition on another column exceeds a threshold or not. The formula looks like this:

```
df.loc[:, 'new_column'] = 0
df.loc[sum(abs(np.diff(df.loc[:, 'old_column']) / df.loc[:, 'old_column'].mean())) > threshold, 'new_column'] = 1
```

However now I don't want to apply this formula to the whole height of the DataFrame, but rather would like to apply a rolling window, i.e. the mean value calculated in the formula rolls through the rows of the DataFrame. I found [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) in the documentation but don't know how I can apply this for a formula like in my case. How could I do something like this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example for clarity? (input+output)

Answer (score 0):

Using column names `a` and `b` instead of `old_column` and `new_column`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=10), columns=['a'])

window = 3
val = df['a'].diff().abs() / df['a'].rolling(window, 1).mean()

threshold = 1
condition = (val > threshold)

df['b'] = 0
df.loc[condition, 'b'] = 1
```

Example results:

```
   a  b
0  1  0
1  7  1
2  6  0
3  1  1
4  8  1
5  2  1
6  3  0
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  8  1
```

Pay close attention to `NaN` values in the intermediate results.  `diff()` returns `nan` in the first row.  This is unlike `np.diff()` because `np.diff()` returns a smaller array than the input.

And `rolling().mean()` will return `NaN` values depending on your `min_periods` parameter.

The final result contains no `NaN` values because `(val > threshold)` is always `False` for `NaN` inputs.